# How can I acces the attributes of a class instance

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to access the attributes of a class instance that are defined inside another class but I keep getting the error that says there is no attribute 'get'.

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Driver:
    proxy = [1, 2, 4]

    def get_driver(self):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        if self.proxy[0] == 1:
            return self

driver = Driver()
driver.get_driver()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xxQs34UMx4&index=101&list=PLihUZHHwjm2GtO_ikMyDg7ot1ENmmYodL")
print driver.proxy
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Your `Driver` class doesn't have a `get` method.

Comment: I don't understand why there should be a `.get` attribute on the instance of `Driver`. It does not inherit any other class and the only defined attributes I can see are `get_driver` and `proxy`.

Comment: You maybe want `__getattribute__` (or the simple dot notation) - but as it stands the question is unclear, your url would be an illegal name for an attribute.

Comment: Whenever you want to find out if a method or variable exists in a library or object, the easiest way is to open python interpreter and do a dir call on your object like `dir(driver)`. This would help you so much in future

Comment: @mauro.stettler .get is a webdriver attribute.

Comment: @EricMacLeod in that case the problem is that get_driver does not return a webdriver instance, it returns either self or None depending on the proxy[0]. The second problem is that get is called on driver, not on the return value of get_driver. Excuse the lack of formatting, I'm on the phone

Answer (score 0):

Your `Driver` class should probably be called `DriverFactory` or something similar. Then your code will look more readable:

```
class DriverFactory(object):
    proxy = [1, 2, 4]

    def get_driver(self):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        if self.proxy[0] == 1:
            return driver
        return None

driver_factory = DriverFactory()
driver = driver_factory.get_driver()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/.....")
print driver_factory.proxy
```

But it still doesnt make sense what the self.proxy part is meant to be doing, and why the return self thing was there in your original code?

Comment: I was just using it as an example, I tried to return self.driver and return driver and it says no attribute 'driver' I just want it to return an object that I can access the driver and the list or tuple whatever I put in a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to access instance's attribute

1. `dir(obj)`
2. `obj.__dict__`
3. using `ipython`'s autocomplete - within the interactive shell, type `obj` <kbd>tab</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I will try to focus on the basics- you can adapt this to your demand.I think you want to automate proxy selection in selenium driver using python, you can try as below-

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

proxies = ["76.9.5.82:65335","45.55.179.51:80","192.99.38.42:35997","40.76.212.171:80","128.136.162.223:3128","104.238.138.253:80","163.153.8.130:1080","208.67.1.154:80","107.151.152.218:80","23.253.208.241:80","104.42.229.65:3128","23.239.134.14:80","46.231.133.106:80","97.77.104.22:80","54.68.135.82:80","178.62.247.158:3128","80.82.64.30:3128","107.151.152.210:80","92.222.93.240:8888","78.46.243.54:3128","69.36.65.214:1080","51.255.192.42:3128","159.122.253.8:3128","51.255.50.106:3128","207.91.10.234:8080","5.45.73.218:80","52.27.22.139:3128","45.63.69.40:8080","206.222.24.100:8080","163.44.119.72:8080"]
def my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
    print PROXY_PORT
    print PROXY_HOST
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4")
    fp.update_preferences()
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)


driver  = my_proxy(*random.choice(proxies).split(':'))
driver.get('https://www.google.com.bd/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=AAOlVoeHM4OtuQT84px4')
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

Acknowledgement: I borrowed some code.

Answer (score -1):

You are applying .get on Driver instance. Try doing instead-

```
    my_driver = driver.get_driver()
    my_driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watchv=5xxQs34UMx4&index=101&list=PLihUZHHjm2GtO_ikMyDg7ot1ENmmYodL")
    print driver.proxy`
```